# Drawing interval at y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can we draw interval from (0,2) to (0,4) to at y axis, we drew it at x axis.

```js
\documentclass[tikz, border={0pt 0pt 0pt 6pt}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% CVS
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7, baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
    \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (6,6);
    \draw[-] (-3,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw (0,0) node[below right] {$0$};
    \draw[-] (0,-2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
    \foreach \x in { -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {-2, -1, 1, 3,6}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$}; 
    \clip (-3,-2) rectangle (6,6);
    \draw[scale=1,smooth,variable=\x,black,domain=-2:1] plot ({\x},{\x});
    \draw[scale=1,smooth,variable=\x,black,domain=1:3] plot ({\x},{(3)*\x});
    \draw[fill=white](1,1) circle(0.7mm);
    \draw[fill=black](1,3) circle(0.7mm);
    \draw[decoration={
        markings, mark=at position .2 with {\arrow[line width=.7\pgflinewidth,scale=2]{[}},
        mark=at position .8 with {\arrow[line width=.7\pgflinewidth,scale=2]{)}}},
    postaction=decorate]
    (+0pt,+0pt) -- node[pos=.2, below=+3pt] {} node[pos=.8, below=+3pt] {} ++(right:+70pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0pt,
              node contents={}}
                        ]    
\draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (6,6);
% axis and ticks
\draw[-] (-3,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0,-2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
    \foreach \x in { -2, -1,...,4}
\draw (\x,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[fill=white,anchor=north]    {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in { -2, -1,1,3,5}
\draw (2pt,\y) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[anchor=east]     {$\y$};
% function   
\draw[thick]    (-2,-2) -- (1,1)  node[dot=white]
                (1,3) node[dot=black] -- (2,6);
%  INTERVAL
\draw[{Parenthesis[width=4mm]}-{Bracket[width=4mm]}, thick] (0,2) -- (0,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @M.O, you are welcome. However, on this site people express thankfulness with upvoting answer(s) and the best from among of goteen accept (by clicking on the *up triangle* and/or *check mark*, which are at top left side of answer. As far as I could see, so far you have not accepted any of the received answers.

Comment: No, I upvoted. Moreover, thank you so much

Comment: @M.O, thank you, however you not accepted it :-). You still wait on the better answer? What you missing in mine?

Comment: I did it now. Sorry!